# converting Git Repo to Mercurial

Tags: git, github, mercurial

I have converted my Git Repo to hg following  [This Link](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2009/10/17/convert-git-repository-to-mercurial/) and its done but now I want to push the repo on the mercurial so it show me all the history and the commits and may be branches too.

I tried by creating  a new repo on my mercurial account and committed code using sourceTree. Repo was created ok but I dont see the history or commits or any branch.

Any idea how to push ?

- Vish

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to convert between Git & Hg is to open a [free KilnHg / Fogbugz account](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/StudentAndStartup.html), create a private repo, push one format to it then pull in the other format, it works with both Git & Hg and (should) do seamless conversions.

Comment: I have one account and have created repo on kiln. @CAD bloke  can you explain it  "create a private repo, push one format to it then pull in the other format"

Comment: Sure. Eg. If you already have a Mercurial Repo, push it to the empty Kiln repo. Then clone that Kiln repo locally in a new folder using a Git client. Job done.

Comment: Sourcetree does both Hg & Git if you're looking for an all-in-one client